# 16.04 apt update error: arm64 Packages not found

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

While trying to update on my Ubuntu 16.04 system I get the following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::17 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.24 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried the solutions suggested here: [16.04 Upgrade: Failed to fetch Empty files can't be valid archives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762273/16-04-upgrade-failed-to-fetch-empty-files-cant-be-valid-archives/779297)

but none of them worked for me. I've had this problem for a while now.
My architecture is

```
amd64
```

Foreign archs are

```
i386
arm64
```

I cannot simply remove the ARM architecture because it is needed for the NVidia SDK I'm developing with.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This happens because the server is unavailable. You might want to change your mirror from your regional to main, while waiting your regional mirror online again. Read more: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main

Comment: The mirror you tried using does NOT contain arm64, have a look in http://ubuntu-master.mirror.tudos.de/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/ and you'll note no arm64.  Whilst [to my knowledge] all mirrors have x86_64, you'll have to check with the arm64 arch[itecure]

Comment: @AryoAdhi Servers that aren't available are hardly available to give a 404 HTTP response.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get rid of arm64 in apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917081/how-to-get-rid-of-arm64-in-apt)

Comment: Not it's not. Please see my edit.

Comment: The question is an exact duplicate, down to the outputs you edited in.

Comment: No, you haven't read carefully: " I cannot simply remove the ARM architecture because it is needed for the NVidia SDK I'm developing with." I managed to solve the problem though, see below.

Answer (score 13):

Ok so I figured out both what's the problem (thanks to you guys) and how to solve it:

The problem was that the NVidia Driveworks SKD seems to mess with apt, as in that apt tries to look for updates on the ARM architecture as well and there is no such path in the predefined package path (thanks, [@guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996103/16-04-update-packages-not-found#comment1608491_996103)).
Since I can't remove the architecture because I need it for development, I changed the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file by adding `[arch=amd64,i386]` where necessary. Example:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe main restricted multiverse
```

Apt is then only looking for updates on those two architectures. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You say your architecture is `amd64`, so I suggest you to find in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all the files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that are not downloading properly and add `[arch=amd64]`.

For example, change

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

URL into

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

Before editing, make a backup of these files. Once edited, try to update again your system.

Be careful. I never had to do this but if you save backups, it can't hurt.

Comment: The lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` only go as long as `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, and don't include the CPU architecture.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: Sorry, I will edit my answer. Try that (after necessary backups).

Answer (score -1):

Untick the unnecessary PPA's in the other software menu and the again try sudo update. 404 errors are mostly due to broken or dead links. This might solve  your problem. If your problem still remains unsolved, follow https://askubuntu.com/a/92897/779822

Comment: What do you mean by "other software menu"?

Comment: The errors aren't from PPAs, since the webserver `de.archive.ubuntu.com` will hardly know what PPAs are installed on your system in order to know that you should be punished with a 404. PPAs come from the server `ppa.launchpad.net`, which is a different server.

Comment: @emilaz in the settings menu, open software &updates, there you must be having a other software tab.