# Error in apt-get update, 404's on "/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages"

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, updates

I have an nvidia jetson tx2, running sudo apt-get update, I get:

```
    Fetched 17.1 MB in 29s (577 kB/s)                                    
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.19.16.188 80]
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I put the link in a browser, indeed it is 404. How do I fix this, what is the correct directory?

Comment: Many mirrors do not contain `arm64` 'arch' (mirroring only x86, x86_64) so use mirrors only for x86 unless you've checked they have what you want (or limit your usage to only i386/x86_64).   eg. `deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://....`

Comment: Futhermore, that terrible NVIDIA setup it also breaks other package updates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/996103/16-04-update-packages-not-found/996117 I got rid of it with: `sudo apt-get purge 'cuda-*:arm64' && sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64`. Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/996103/16-04-update-packages-not-found/996117